# Godot 3.2 wont accept my custom build Sdk path in editor settings

Tags: android, sdk, export, godot

I'm trying to export a project in Godot 3.2 on Android. I can export it without toggling custom settings but when I try to use the custom settings, I get an error message "-Invalid Android Sdk path for custom build in editor settings"
[Image of error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiwZr.png)
I have accepted all the sdk licenses, so I don't know why its doing this
the path I'm currently using is: "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning,

After two days of trial and error, we have just found the solution:

Download the command-line-tools :
https://developer.android.com/studio/#command-tools
Unzip it, then copy and paste the "tools" folder into the Android SDK:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDxtG.jpg

Hopefully this will solve your problem.